# Ubuntu for a laptop

Tags: laptop

Good morning.

What would be the most appropriate ubuntu version for an older laptop that has previously run Windows vista? I want to use it as an educational tool for my 12 year old son.

Comment: Ubuntu's main products are in the format *year.month*, so Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop is the 2020-April release of Ubuntu Desktop. It's also available for server, and some products use the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20 being the 2020 release of that product) but products using the *year* format are specialist (designed for devices, appliances or cloud use & not desktop/laptops).

Comment: Does the laptop have a 64-bit CPU?

Comment: You didn't give any specs of the device; but I used devices as old as 2003 design/manufacture for QA (Quality Assurance) testing up to 19.04 (2019-April release) but they were 32-bit (i386), where as Vista implies it's *amd64* (AMD created the 64-bit compatible architecture so even intels are *amd64*) releases apply from then on (inc. Ubuntu Desktop from 17.10; only *flavors* of Ubuntu applied for 32-bit after mid-2017).  A lighter *flavor* may be best for low powered devices.

Comment: I suggest you consider Lubuntu. I have used this on many older laptops; it runs very well. Without knowing what hardware components are in your laptop, nobody can advise your further.   https://lubuntu.me/